# Installation error with google app engine

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine

I am receiving the following error when attempting to run Google App Engine's skeleton app:

```
Command    
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Flask/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install 
--record /tmp/pip-T6smcg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-
externally-managed --compile --home=/tmp/tmpnvqz95 failed with error 
code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Flask
```

As per their documentation, I downloaded their app skeleton by git cloning `appengine-python-flask-skeleton.git`.

However, when I attempt to actually install the requirements using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib
```

I get the error that I pasted above. I've tried manually inspecting the requirements file, and it appears that Flask is the only requirement, which pip freeze has shown me I have. Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

What version of pip do you have installed?

```
pip --version
```

I'm going out on a limb that you have a version installed < 1.4. Which means you need to upgrade pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: pip 1.5.6 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: Weird. Perhaps try removing / reinstalling flask directly from pypi?

Comment: I'm starting to think that the problem is that the version of python that pip installs to and the version of python that is returned via `which python` are different, based on the packages that are available when I do `pip freeze` vs `import x` out of a python prompt. I've been looking through stackoverflow but have not found a good way to fix this so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with homebrew python and pip's `-t` option. Make sure you're using the latest pip you can use.